# find a date in a powershell variable

Tags: powershell

I have parsed text file:

`$Sel = select-string -pattern "Date=*" -path D:\test_file.txt -List`

and here is the result:

```
D:\test_file.txt:3: <aaa="000000" Date="2016-12-05"> <bbbbb="cccc" dddd="20161209" eeee="2016-12-09" fff="ggggg" hhhh="hhh" aaaa="1" bbbb="100" cccc="100">
```

I have tried to run regex on it

```
 $regex = "(19|20)[0-9]{2}[- -.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- -.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])"
```

to parse this again as

```
select-string -pattern $regex -InputObject $Sel
```

but that didn't work. Do you have any ideas how to find the date in that above string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be correct:

```
$sel -match $regex
$date = $matches[0]
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I define $date?

Comment: The date you want is in $matches[0], I just put it in another variable as $matches[0] is a system variable and can be overwritten by another regex match so you should extract it ASAP.

If the second line was just $matches[0] it would write your date to the output.

Comment: ok ran it and here is the result: `PS C:\$sel -match $regex
True` then $date = $matches[0], zero results

Comment: You can now just type $date to expand the variable into your date.

Comment: Glad to help, if you could accept this as the answer, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

If the date pattern always is in the specified form `Date="yyyy-MM-dd"`, the most straightforward way is to look for that pattern. No need to worry about 1900's and 2000's at all. Like so,

```
# Test data
$sel = 'D:\test_file.txt:3:< aaa="000000" Date="2016-12-05" >'

# Let's match date that starts with Date= literal
[regex]$rex = 'Date="(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})"'

# Print the result if matched
if($rex.Match($sel).groups.count -eq 2) {
    $rex.Match($sel).groups[1].value
}
```